# How to compare the current value of a variable with the previous value?

Tags: bash, shell

Can you tell me how to add to this script to compare every 10 minutes the result of the previous ID value with the current one, if the previous value is equal to the current one notify in telegram.

```
#!/bin/bash
id=`curl -X GET "$HOST" | jq '.res[0].id | tonumber'`
for ((a=$id;a<=999999999;a++))
do

sleep 10; echo "Start $a:"
done
```

The first part of the code is a sample. Naturally, there is a function that is executed with the $a variable. I need to add a function that checks the current id with the previous one and notifies if the values are the same. i.e. if the current id is 5 and the previous id is 5, notify telegram. And this check should be done every 10 minutes.

```
TELEGRAM_BOT_TOKEN=""
TELEGRAM_CHAT_ID=""
send_telegram() {
    curl -s -X POST "https://api.telegram.org/bot$TELEGRAM_BOT_TOKEN/sendMessage" -d chat_id=$TELEGRAM_CHAT_ID -d text="$1"
}
```

Comment: What is `$a`? Why `\jq` instead of `jq`? What prevents you from saving `$id` as `$prev_id` and comparing them in the loop? Did you see [ask] yet?

Comment: `sleep 10` sleeps 10 seconds, not 10 minutes, see `man sleep`.

Comment: AND ... can we safely assume that `$id` will always be a decimal integer (1-9999999)? ALSO Please read  the section [How to turn a bad script into a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info). Going thru this process will often help you solve your problem by yourself. Good luck.

Comment: [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) identifies several problems with the code.  The report that it produces includes links to more information about the problems and how to fix them.  It's a good idea to run [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) on all new and modified shell code.

Comment: Basic approach. `id=...` now enter your loop `for ((a...)); do if [ -n "$lastid" ] && [ "$id" = "$lastid" ]; then echo "id and lastid: $id"; fi; lastid="$id"; sleep 10; id=...; done` Here you just set `id` before entering loop. if `lastid` is set and it equals `id` then output or do something. Now set `lastid="$id"`, `sleep` and get a new `id`. Repeat until done.

Comment: `sleep 600` is 10 minutes.